# how to find y value from line/curve intersection?

Tags: octave

Octave beginner, I'd like to calculate the y position of the point located in the blue circle (intersection of c1 and v1).

Any tip on how to do that ?

Here is the plot:

[image]

Below is my code

```
vertical=30000

a = [ 0 2000 4000 6000 12000 24000 48000 ]
b = a
c = [ 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 ]
d = []
index=1
for i = a
    d(index)=i-(i*c(index)/100)
    index+=1
end

# plotting
ymax=max(a)
plot(a,b,"-;l1;","linewidth",3,"color",[0.5 0.5 0.5])
hold on
plot(a,d,"-;c1;","linewidth",3)
plot([vertical,vertical],[0,ymax],"-;v1;","linewidth", 3)

axis ([0 ymax 0 ymax])
axis ("tic", "square");
axis ("tic", "label");
grid on
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Basically you have a few points and you want to 'interpolate', i.e. find a point between your well-defined points. Have a look at the `interp1` function.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Tasos, it works.

```
y = interp1 (a,d,vertical)
```

And the result is

```
y = 13800
```